# How to write mmap input memory to O_DIRECT output file?

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap

why doesn't following pseudo-code work (O_DIRECT results in EFAULT)

```
in_fd = open("/dev/mem");
in_mmap = mmap(in_fd);
out_fd = open("/tmp/file", O_DIRECT);
write(out_fd, in_mmap, PAGE_SIZE);
```

while following does (no O_DIRECT)

```
in_fd = open("/dev/mem");
in_mmap = mmap(in_fd);
out_fd = open("/tmp/file");
write(out_fd, in_mmap, PAGE_SIZE);
```

I guess it's something with virtual kernel pages to virtual user pages, which cannot be translated in the write call?

Best regards,

Friedrich

Comment: `O_DIRECT` writes need to pin the pages; maybe that is the problem...  What are you actually trying to do?  If this is a memory-mapped hardware device, you might be better off adding `splice` support to the driver...  Also, please provide a more complete example (including all flags to all system calls).  Ideally one that anybody could compile and run to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Using mmap() with O_DIRECT is tricky. There are some restrictions. The output to the file should be block aligned. For example, if you set offset in mmap() to 0 your code will work. You have to check the block size of your filesystem to set that value properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. Use `CMA` and `vm_insert_pages`. Detailed instructions can be found in [my another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73032605/6949852)
2. Use `no-map` reserved memory combined with [my patch series](https://lwn.net/Articles/900703/). This series includes a sample that demonstrates how to implement this approach easily.