# How to implement or emulate MADV_ZERO?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, mmap, fallocate

I would like to be able to zero out a range of a file memory-mapping without invoking any io (in order to efficiently sequentially overwrite huge files without incurring any disk read io).

Doing `std::memset(ptr, 0, length)` will cause pages to be read from disk if they are not already in memory even if the entire pages are overwritten thus totally trashing disk performance.

I would like to be able to do something like `madvise(ptr, length, MADV_ZERO)` which would zero out the range (similar to [`FALLOC_FL_ZERO_RANGE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html)) in order to cause zero fill page faults instead of regular io page faults when accessing the specified range.

Unfortunately `MADV_ZERO` does not exists. Even though the corresponding flag [`FALLOC_FL_ZERO_RANGE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) does exists in [`fallocate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) and can be used with `fwrite` to achieve a similar effect, though without instant cross process coherency.

One possible alternative I would guess is to use [`MADV_REMOVE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html). However, that can from my understanding cause file fragmentation and also blocks other operations while completing which makes me unsure of its long term performance implications. My experience with Windows is that the similar [`FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364597(v=vs.85).aspx) command can incur significant performance spikes when invoked.

My question is how one could implement or emulate `MADV_ZERO` for shared mappings, preferably in user mode?

## 1. **`/dev/zero/`**

I have read it being [suggested](https://lkml.org/lkml/2000/2/24/102) to **simply read `/dev/zero` into the selected range**. Though I am not quite sure what "reading into the range" means and how to do it. Is it like a `fread` from `/dev/zero` into the memory range? Not sure how that would avoid a regular page fault on access?

> For Linux, simply read `/dev/zero` into the selected range.  The
>   kernel    already optimises this case for anonymous mappings.
>
> If doing it in general turns out to be too hard to implement, I
>   propose MADV_ZERO should have this effect: exactly like reading
>   /dev/zero into the range, but always efficient.

EDIT: Following the thread a bit [further](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0002.3/0127.html) it turns out that it will actually not work.

> It does not do tricks when you are dealing with a shared mapping.

## 2. **`MADV_REMOVE`**

One guess of implementing it in Linux (i.e. not in user application which is what I would prefer) could be by simply copying and modifying `MADV_REMOVE`, i.e. [`madvise_remove`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/64e22b86854227b4d13a57fa02f26472bc426812/mm/madvise.c#L293) to use [`FALLOC_FL_ZERO_RANGE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) instead of [`FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html). Though I am bit over my head in guessing this, especially as I don't quite understand what the code around the `vfs_allocate` is doing:

```
// madvice.c
static long madvise_remove(...)
  ...
  /*
   * Filesystem's fallocate may need to take i_mutex.  We need to
   * explicitly grab a reference because the vma (and hence the
   * vma's reference to the file) can go away as soon as we drop
   * mmap_sem.
   */
  get_file(f); // Increment ref count.
  up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem); // Release a read lock? Why?
  error = vfs_fallocate(f,
            FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, // FALLOC_FL_ZERO_RANGE?
            offset, end - start);
  fput(f); // Decrement ref count.
  down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem); // Acquire read lock. Why?
  return error;
}
```

Comment: Quite possibly the *"simply read `/dev/zero` into the selected range"* refers to the [following technique seen in `shmem_zero_setup()` within the Linux kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/shmem.c?v=4.1#L3395).

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: Not quite sure what to make out of that...

Comment: Start from [`do_mmap_pgoff()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/mmap.c?v=4.1#L1247) with `flags = MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE` and follow the code-path till `shmem_zero_setup()` for a complete picture. For an anonymous mapping, in the absence of a file backing a zero-page is used initially to optimise reads. Of-course this is NOT a solution to your problem. Its just an example of a proper implementation that you can refer to if you want to implement the suggestion yourself within the kernel.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are going to write a fixed pattern of blocks to the disk (i.e. long sequence of zeroes), why not open the filefile in `O_DIRECT | O_WRONLY`, `lseek()` to the proper offset and simply dump large blocks (multiples of disk block size) until `len` number of bytes are zerou-ed out. Apparently this [works with a couple of alignment and offset restrictions on `mmap()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9775374/319204). What do you think?...

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: That would work if I was only writing to the file. But other processes are reading from the memory just a few seconds later so I need the data in cache. Basically I need to combine IPC with persistance.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: Thanks for code-path. Though that is a bit to advanced for me right now. I might get back to it later. I just switched to Linux after 10 years of Windows and Visual Studio.

Comment: **IPC with persistence** brings back some golden memories of yesteryear. I was playing around with mmap-ed files with the exact same intention. I was using **inotify** to monitor the **file-backed "shared-memory"**. As there was no [equivalent to `sync()` that i could call to trigger a "inotification", i wrote one](https://gist.github.com/TheCodeArtist/5874669). :P In my design, the *writer* thread would updates all the relevant fields in the memory-mapped shared-file and finally trigger a `msync()` upon which the *reader* thread(s) waiting using inotify would be unblocked. I hope it helps...

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: That does help. Currently I am using atomic write/reads to "tags" in the mapped memory and then simply poll in the reader. Your solution sounds safer and more efficient. However, it still doesn't solve *this* problem with the significantly reduced throughput caused by the unnecessary page-faults when overwriting.

Comment: Glad to know that. However I cannot claim to be the original source of the idea though. IIRC, i managed to fish some half-baked code off the "internets" and ironed it out to fit my use-case. Googling "inotify IN_SYNC" should point you to few LKML discussions on the rationale/implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot do what you want (in user space, without hacking the kernel). Notice that writing zero pages might not incur physical disk IO because of the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

You might want to replace a file segment by a file hole (but this is not exactly what you want) in a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), but some file systems (e.g. VFAT) don't have holes or sparse files. See [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) with `SEEK_HOLE`, [ftruncate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html)

Comment: Yes, that is what `MADV_REMOVE` accomplishes. However, as we both noted, it causes the file to become sparse and also punching the hole locks the file from all other operations while completing (which in .e.g Windows is very slow, haven't tested on Linux as of yet). Which makes me sceptical about its long term performance implications. The use case I need this for is 24/7 writes without any time for defragmentation.

Comment: I believe you actually have the same problem with the file/page cache. Since the page cache itself uses memory mapped sections but on larger boundaries. Not sure though.