# Write from mmapped buffer to `O_DIRECT` output file

Tags: io, linux-kernel, mmap

I have a device which writes to a video buffer. This buffer is allocated in system memory using CMA and I want to implement streaming write from this buffer to a block device. My application opens video buffer with mmap and I would like to use `O_DIRECT` write to avoid page cache related overhead. Basically, the pseudo-code of the application looks like this:

```
f_in = open("/dev/videobuf", O_RDONLY);
f_mmap = mmap(0, BUFFER_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, f_in, 0);
f_out = open("/dev/sda", O_WRONLY | O_DIRECT);
write(f_out, f_mmap, BLOCK_SIZE);
```

where BLOCK_SIZE is sector aligned value. f_out is opened without any errors, but write results in `EFAULT`. I tried to track down this issue and it turned out that mmap implementation in video buffer's driver uses `remap_pfn_range()`, which sets `VM_IO` and `VM_PFNMAP` flags for VMA. The `O_DIRECT` path in block device drivers checks these flags and returns `EFAULT`. As far as I understand, `O_DIRECT` writes need to pin the memory pages, but VMA flags indicate the absence of `struct page` for underlying memory which causes an error. Am I right here?

And the main question is how to correctly implement `O_DIRECT` write from mmapped buffer? I have video buffer driver and can modify it appropriately.

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444744/how-to-write-mmap-input-memory-to-o-direct-output-file), but these is no clear answer there.

Comment: Before modifying the video buffer driver, I'd first see if [`sendfile()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) works:  `off_t offset = 0L; ssize_t byteSent = sendfile( f_out, f_in, &offset, BLOCK_SIZE );`, assuming the video buffer driver doesn't support `lseek()` or otherwise track file offset.  (Or `ssize_t byteSent = sendfile( f_out, f_in, NULL, BLOCK_SIZE );`)  If it works, that would avoid the `mmap()` and the need to pin user-space pages entirely.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I tested `sendfile()` and it does not work in my situation. If `f_in` is a regular file than it works as expected, but if `f_in` is a video buffer than this function returns `EINVAL`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `remap_pfn_range` designates your virtual memory area as `special` by using `pte_mkspecial` and includes `VM_IO/VM_PFNMAP` in the vma. Consequently, it fails specific validations for `Direct I/O`.

Since your memory comes from `CMA` which already supports `struct page`, you can utilize `vm_insert_pages` with the following steps:

1. Add `CMA` region using kernel arguments or device tree source (`DTS`).
2. Get struct pages from CMA:

```
dma_page = dma_alloc_contiguous(&pdev->dev, size, GFP_KERNEL);
if (!dma_page) {
    pr_err("%s %d, dma_alloc_contiguous fail\n", __func__, __LINE__);
    return -ENOMEM;
}
nr_pages = DIV_ROUND_UP(size, PAGE_SIZE);
pages = kvmalloc_array(nr_pages, sizeof(*pages), GFP_KERNEL);
for (i = 0; i < nr_pages; i++)
    pages[i] = &dma_page[i];
```

3. Insert pages into vma when calling `mmap`:

```
int your_mmap(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma) {
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned long temp_nr_pages;

    if (vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start > size)
        return -EINVAL;

    /* Duplicate nr_pages as vm_insert_pages can change nr_pages */
    temp_nr_pages = nr_pages;

    ret = vm_insert_pages(vma, vma->vm_start, pages, &temp_nr_pages);
    if (ret < 0)
        pr_err("%s vm_insert_pages fail, error is %d\n", __func__, ret);

    return ret;
}
```

4. Export `dma_alloc_contiguous` (the only memory management code change, but it's acceptable).

```
modified   kernel/dma/contiguous.c
@@ -332,6 +332,7 @@ struct page *dma_alloc_contiguous(struct device *dev, size_t size, gfp_t gfp)

        return cma_alloc_aligned(dma_contiguous_default_area, size, gfp);  }
+EXPORT_SYMBOL(dma_alloc_contiguous);

 /**
  * dma_free_contiguous() - release allocated pages
```