# using O_DIRECT with IO memory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

I'm trying to write some data to HDD from I/O memory(HIGHMEM).
I have mmap'ed the memory buffer using io_remap_pfn_range().
My application uses O_DIRECT, for disk read/write operation.
Using O_DIRECT, write returns EFAULT (bad address). I tracked this down to __get_user_pages in mm/memory.c where IO pages
are refused. And this is as deep as my current knowledge allows me to
go into the kernel.  I don't understand why IO pointers are not
allowed. Ultra-Fast disk IO is a requirement for our project, so any copying in
between is not an option. Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444744/how-to-write-mmap-input-memory-to-o-direct-output-file/73032642#73032642

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503747/write-from-mmapped-buffer-to-o-direct-output-file/73032605#73032605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that it all happens because of `VM_PFNMAP` flag ( http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11.7/source/include/linux/mm.h#L174 )
When you use `io_remap_pfn_range`, it sets `VM_PFNMAP` flag ( http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11.7/source/mm/memory.c#L1914 ), that tells "those pages aren't regular pages with usual struct page" ( see comment in the code above )
And `__get_user_pages` checks this flag and returns error ( http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11.7/source/mm/nommu.c#L136 )
P.S. There is `VM_IO` flag too in both `io_remap_pfn_range` and `__get_user_pages`, so there won't be any I/O on kernel pages, mapped to user-space, or anyone will rewrite kernel memory